# "In about" or "about in"

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

> 1. He investigated the case in about 1900.
> 2. He investigated the case about in 1900.

Comment: I'd recommend using _around_ before using either of those options. I'd also recommend checking out [ell.se].

Answer (score 1):

If you were limited to these options, the correct one would be the first option:

> He investigated the case in about 1900

The word "about" is added here to indicate uncertainty regarding the year when the investigation happened (we don't know when it exactly happened but it was close to 1900s). Therefore the subject of this uncertainty is "1900s" rather than the "investigation". The second option would place emphasis on the investigation being uncertain rather than when it was carried out. If you add "about" before in, it seems as if it will be used as a preposition for the *location*, such as saying

> He investigated the case about 3rd Avenue

About should, therefore, be placed after in.

As an aside, I agree with J.R. on using around rather than about. That would make the sentence clearer:

> He investigated the case around 1900

or

> He investigated the case circa 1900

Comment: No _in_, just _around_: **He investigated the case around 1900**. As a footnote, in a more formal context, you could use [_circa_](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning+of+circa) instead.